# Why cant I acess my getters and setters from the main?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I am trying to solve a problem that collects information from a file and stores it in an ArrayList. I cant seem to figure out why I cant access the methods from the class I created. In each line of the file you have the name of two teams and its scores in each game. I need to ask the user which team he wants me to look for and if I can find the name, present the totalGames the team played. I would also need to compare the scores and print total games won and total games lost. My idea was creating a method to split the string in multiple parts and add those info as attributes to a new object in an ArrayList.

Here is the class Games:

```
    public class Game {
    String homeTeam;
    String visitorTeam;
    int homePoints;
    int visitorPoints;
    
    
    public Game(String home, String visitor,int hPoints,int vPoints){
        this.homeTeam = home;
        this.visitorTeam = visitor;
        this.homePoints = hPoints;
        this.visitorPoints = vPoints;
    }

    public String getHomeTeam() {
        return homeTeam;
    }

    public String getVisitorTeam() {
        return visitorTeam;
    }

    public int getHomePoints() {
        return homePoints;
    }

    public int getVisitorPoints() {
        return visitorPoints;
    }
    
    @Override
   public String toString(){
       return homeTeam + visitorTeam + homePoints + visitorPoints;
   }
}
```

and here is how my main is looking like so far:

```
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SportStatistics {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("File:");
        String file = scan.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Team:");
        String team = scan.nextLine();
        
       
        ArrayList<Game> gameInfo = readRecordsFromFile(file);
        System.out.println(gameInfo);
        
     gameInfo.getHomeTeam();

    }

    public static ArrayList<Game> readRecordsFromFile(String file) {
        ArrayList<Game> information = new ArrayList<>();
        try ( Scanner read = new Scanner(Paths.get(file))) {
            while (read.hasNextLine()) {
                String info = read.nextLine();

                if (info.isEmpty()) {
                    continue;
                }

                String[] parts = info.split(",");
                String homeTeam = parts[0];
                String visitorTeam = parts[1];
                int homePoints = Integer.valueOf(parts[2]);
                int visitorPoints = Integer.valueOf(parts[3]);

                information.add(new Game(homeTeam, visitorTeam, homePoints, visitorPoints));
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
        return information;

    }

}
```

Comment: `gameInfo` is an `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for(Game g : gameInfo){
   System.out.println(g.getHomeTeam());
}
```

This should do it a simple for each loop to grab each game out of the list (g) and prints the home team for each game.

You can also do

```
for(int i = 0; i < gameInfo.size(); i++){
    System.out.println(g.getHomeTeam());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

gameInfo is of type ArrayList here. You will have to iterate the list first the you will be able to call getters and setters.

```
gameInfo.forEach(ob->System.out.println(ob.getHomeTeam()));
```

Comment: Is that type of iteration you are talking about ?                                                                for(int i = 0; i < gameInfo.size(); i++){
         gameInfo.get(i);
     }

Comment: Yes, this is with Java 8. Which version of java you are using?

Comment: I am using Java 15

Comment: then this way of iteration should work with Java 15 also.

Answer (score 0):

gameInfo is a arrayList of class Game. You will have to iterate through the list to get the object. The getters and setters can only be accessed with these objects.
You can use a **for loop or a for-each loop** for this purpose.